# Is there a pattern for getting the right database entry

Tags: angular, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to use Spring+Angular for an application where I need to access Data from my MySQL Database and present it to the user and save changes back into the same entry where it was before (so update a database entry). That means my data goes:

```
Database -(Hibernate)-> Spring -(REST)-> Angular -(REST)-> Spring -(Hibernate)-> Database
```

So I need to find the right object to update it when I return my set. I plan to use a Map for this in my backend, but this seems like a (bad) workaround and I cannot inmagine that similar problems are solved this way.

Is there a design pattern for this use case?

To be more specific on my use-case:

Inmagine a table `Foo` with the attributes `FooID, FooValue`. Now I display these to the user in my frontend and the user changes the `FooValue`. How can I find the right `FooID` for my `FooValue` assuming `FooValue` is not unique?

**My actual solution idea:**

Send the updated `FooValue` to a REST-controller with the `FooID` that I save as attribute in HTML-cells and then use the map to map it to the right `Foo`-object, update the value of this Object and finally use Hibernate to save it in my database.

**Edit:**

I am not sure if this is an opinion-based questions and I tried to formulate it as an not-opinion-based question since I am asking for an example pattern that can be used (does not have to be the best solution or something like this).

Comment: Of course you must send the ID of the row you want to update. That's exactly what IDs are for. You shouldn't use a hidden field in a HTML cell to store it: it should be part of the URL used to display the page used to edit the Foo. (Just like the URL of this page contains the ID of your question). And why would you need a Map? You have a database. So just get the entity from the database by its ID, modify it, and let Hibernate save it for you.

Comment: @JBNizet I need the ID in my HTML-cell it identify which object got changed, since my `Foo`-Table contains a lot of entries which are all displayed within the same table for the user. I did not know another way to remember which entry is displayed in which cell of the UI.        If this is a common way to solve my problem and there is no other pattern used, it is even better for me! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's in your model. Your HTML template uses an *ngFor to iterate over Foo objects stored in an array of your component, and each Foo object has an ID. No need to have this ID in the HTML.

Comment: JB has good advice. I would add that if you “use a Map”, it will make your server stateful, which is in general bad, because it’s more complicated, but also you can’t run multiple instances without sharing the “Map” between instances, which is harder and messier than you might think. The DB is the correct and best place to store the state of your Foo objects - it’s easy for everyone to agree on what the state is. See [ACID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science))